# C# Compiler: Preprocess Only

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

I plan on distributing [SubSpec](https://bitbucket.org/johannesrudolph/subspec/) ( a small BDD extension for xUnit which fits into < 600 lines) as a single .cs file instead of a full blown dll.

SubSpec has a Silverlight and .NET flavor, it would be ideal to build release versions of SubSpec from a single master file by pulling it through the CSC Preprocessor. By a "release version" I mean creating that single cs file (there will be no binary releases). Versioning will be handled by NuGet.

I understand that the C# compiler does not have a separate preprocessor (instead it's integrated into the pipeline). Are there other compilers/tools that I could use instead of CSC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tools/install.ps1` can do what it wants to the C# file as it's being 'installed' so it could process it during inclusion - that could be either by using embedded `$(x)` or `$(expression)` items in a multi-line string which expand conditionally (possibly by having a set of `function`s that expand to C# code as `[string]`s forming components of the expression), i.e., templating, or you can pipe the `Get-Content` through some `-replace`s. (You'll probably see examples around of people using T4 for that too, but if NuGet is the delivery truck, it's be a shame not to use it. If you're feeling adventurous, you could do a real parser (or just a poor man's one) in there too.

Another way may be to use `partial` classes and let the `install.ps1` slot in the right customiser file beside the main one.

Or else you just havent tried hard enough to [optimise out your `#ifdef SILVERLIGHT`s](http://jorudolph.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/improving-conditional-compilation/) using [tricks like this to get back on your horse](http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2010/11/16/how-to-make-sharing-code-between-net-and-silverlight-a-little-less-painful.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You could always just run it through the C++ preprocessor via `cl /E /P`, and you're already guaranteed to have it installed on (almost) every VS installation. That's a very old-school trick though :)

```
// SubSpec.cs
// Bla bla license stuff

#include "File1.cs"  // This gets read by the C++ preprocessor
#include "File2.cs"  // and expanded out
#include "File3.cs"
```

Comment: sounds like a good idea, I will try that. I don't want to do includes (although it opens a few options...), only want to create a single cs file that has no SILVERLIGHT conditionals in it (reduces bloat, get me close to the magic 500 lines).

Comment: +1 Nice hack, but lots of people try to save the few hundred megs so not a great assumption (I know you know that)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the .cs file to the project where it is required?

If you want to reference the file from a common location then you can manually edit the .csproj file to use an absolute (or relative) path, instead of using the one in the project directory.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. By a "release version" I mean creating that single cs file (there will be no binary releases). Versioning will be handled by NuGet.